# Trouble counting rows with specific value - Doctrine, Symfony2, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on querying my mysql database via doctrine in a symfony2 app. I have a basic table set up that includes an id number ('id'), name ('name'), and a last column for if the person has been contacted ('contacted'), depicted with 0 or 1. I can query and get the number of total inquiries (depicted in the controller with $inquiryCountTotal just fine.

I'm struggling to count the rows that have been contacted. I figure I can either COUNT the rows with a value of 1 in the contacted column or I could just SUM all the rows in the contacted column.

For some reason it seems to be summing the ids, as I have 8 ids and it's spitting a number of 36.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('EABundle:Inquiry')
        ->findBy(array(), array('id'=>'DESC'));

    $inquiryCountTotal = $em->createQuery("
        SELECT count(id)
        FROM   EABundle:Inquiry id
    ")->getSingleScalarResult();

    //This is the part I'm struggling with...

    $inquiryCount = $em->createQuery("
        SELECT sum(contacted)
        FROM   EABundle:Inquiry contacted
    ")->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $this->render('EABundle:Inquiry:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
        'inquiryCount' => $inquiryCount,
        'inquiryCountTotal' => $inquiryCountTotal
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine is interpreting the alias as the id of the entity.

Try this:

```
$inquiryCount = $em->createQuery("
    SELECT sum(i.contacted)
    FROM   EABundle:Inquiry i
")->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: Your welcome.  I learned this behavior of Doctrine by looking at Symfony's Profiler and viewing runnable queries.  Very informative.

Comment: How can I avoid the default join in tables?

Comment: @RodolVelasco This should be posted as a new question.  Be sure to provide details showing apparent default joins.